# how to display information from a .dat file in a jfram using textarea

Tags: java, eclipse, jtextarea

I am trying to crate a database.
however everytime I try and display my  log file, nothing happens. 
the frame opens but there is nothing but my button and scroll bar in it.
Everything runs but it will not display what I have in my .dat file.
how do I bring my JTextArea from my public void to my main? 
Also am I reading from the file properly?
Is there any other way I should do this?

```
public class displaylog extends JFrame {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    displaylog newerconcoles = new displaylog();
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {

            try {
                displaylog frame = new displaylog();
                frame.getContentPane();
                frame.setVisible(true);

                final JTextArea edit = readFromFile();

                frame.getContentPane().add(edit);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

     });

  }

  public displaylog() throws IOException {
    setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
            "H:\\Downloads\\potato-03.jpg"));
    setTitle("Inventory 3000 and 1");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 616, 447);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton btnMainMenu = new JButton("Main Menu");
    btnMainMenu.setBounds(250, 386, 113, 23);
    getContentPane().add(btnMainMenu);
    btnMainMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            newframe regFace = new newframe();
            regFace.setVisible(true);
            dispose();
        }
     });

    JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar();
    scrollBar.setBounds(582, 38, 16, 272);
    getContentPane().add(scrollBar);
 }

  public static JTextArea readFromFile() {
    String fileName = "MasterLog.dat";
    final JTextArea edit = new JTextArea(40, 60);
    edit.setBackground(Color.RED);
    edit.setEditable(false);
    edit.setBounds(584, 43, -556, 272);
    try {
        Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
        String[] lines = Files.readAllLines(new File(fileName).toPath(),
                charset).toArray(new String[0]);

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            edit.append(lines[i]);
            System.out.println(lines[i]);
            edit.append("\n");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File Not Found (Check Path)");

    }
    return edit;

    }
 }
```

Comment: How can something have a negative width; `edit.setBounds(584, 43, -556, 272);`?

Comment: [`JTextArea#read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read-java.io.Reader-java.lang.Object-)?

Comment: ok thanks that was the problem

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: There's no need to use `JScrollBar`, just wrap the `JTextArea` in a `JScrollPane`, see [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) and [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details